# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'orangecontrib'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install Orange package

I went to their website and follow exactly what has been said following this link

https://orange.biolab.si/download/

I have anaconda and install it through command prompt Windows 10 pc

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

and approved installing all additional packages

I opened my jupyter notebook and pip installed

```
!pip install orange3
```

nothing went up

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Orange
from Orange.data import Domain, DiscreteVariable, ContinuousVariable
```

This turns out to be okay but when I do

```
from orangecontrib.associate.fpgrowth import *
```

Things do not work up as expected with the following error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'orangecontrib'
```

I am working as the following [link](https://github.com/dipanjanS/practical-machine-learning-with-python/blob/master/notebooks/Ch08_Customer_Segmentation_and_Effective_Cross_Selling/cross_selling.py)

[image]

Comment: if you're using python3-x, then use pip3 (not pip)

Comment: or see similar solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50048812/3256489

Answer (score 4):

I've also faced that problem. You'll have to install the associated Orange libraries:

```
pip3 install Orange3-Associate
```