# No-module named pandas-datareader

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pandas-datareader

for mac, I have used

```
pip3 install pandas_datareader
```

and the cmd shows it is successful.

but when I try to import pandas_datareader in jupyter,

it shows me "No module named pandas_datareader"

my python version is 3.6

so what's the problem,and how could i do to fix it?

thanks all~

Comment: do you have multiple virtual env ?
Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/39028927/3256489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a global solution](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook).
Your case may be solved by

- `python -m pip install <package>` (mentioned there, avoid using `sudo` ... but it's up to you)
- or directly to install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel:

In [1]:

> ```
> import sys
> !{sys.executable} -m pip install <package>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

are you on windows or linux??
if linux:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas_datareader
```

This is the most saftest way to install any module in python when we have multiple versions in system installed.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I have written that:on mac,not windows or linux~