# Orange3 model load in python

Tags: orange

I made model.pkcls in Orange3-3.32.0 GUI mode.

I want to load the model.pkcls created by Orange3 in Jupyter Notebook Python.

I ran Jupyter Notebook as administrator to install the Orange3 module.

```
!pip install Orange3
!pip3 install Orange3-Associate
import Orange
import pickle
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkcls', 'rb'))
```

To load model.pkcls created in Orange3. But I get an error called `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'orangecontrib.text'`

Before, I had a error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'orangecontrib'`.
Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906594/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-orangecontrib). So I did `!pip3 install Orange3-Associate`.

And when I run it, I got this problem. No matter how much I search, I don't see this error. In this case, how to solve it? Or is there another way to load the model?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install the `Orange3-Text` which is an Orange3 [add-on](https://pypi.org/project/Orange3-Text/), try this code:

```py
!pip install Orange3
!pip install Orange3-Associate
!pip install Orange3-Text

import Orange
import pickle

model = pickle.load(open('model.pkcls', 'rb'))
```

The missing module `orangecontrib.text` is part of the Orange3-Text add-on, which is not shipped with the default Orange3 installation packages.